# Keeping list entries when I move activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView. 
I populate this list from 2 editTexts
When I move activity and go back to it the entries are gone again. 
I kind of understand why this is but dont know how to correct it.

```
    ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"planet"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "testme"));
    lv2.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);


    button21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iinitList();
            simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText5.setText("");
            editText6.setText("");
        }
    });

}




    private void iinitList() {

    String st,str;
    Double db;
    if (editText5.getText().toString()!= "" && editText6.getText().toString()!="") {
        st = editText5.getText().toString();
        str = editText6.getText().toString();
        db = Double.parseDouble(str);

            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", ""+st+
                    ": \n" +db+""));

    }

}
HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    planet.put(key, name);
    return planet;
}
```

As you can see I have added a value to the list manually called test also, when I move activity this stays in the list, I would love if the editText entries were to stay in there also when I move activities.

Comment: then you have to save it [somehow](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities can be destroyed when you navigate to a new one or rotate.  This will clear anything that is only referenced by the activity, like your EditTexts.  However, Android provides a nice utility for saving things you want to remain in a method called, which you can override in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    // Put your values in the state bundle here
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    // Load your UI elements as usual

    if (savedState != null) {
        // Load your state from the bundle
    }
}
```

That same bundle will be given back to you in onCreate, where you create your UI to begin with so you can reload the state from it.

This is a really good description of how activities work:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html